# What's the best free resource to learn about Ms IIS?

Tags: iis, outsystems

I usually use IIS in conjunction with the OutSystems development platform, which does code-generation for web applications.

As it does the compiling and deployment of the applications to IIS, I end up knowing very little on how it really works, and sometimes it is very useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://learn.iis.net/

Answer (score 0):

The one I've found really helpful is [the official IIS site by Microsoft](http://www.iis.net/). Lots of helpful articles, downloads and advice from knowledgable guys in the forums.

Were you after some specific advice/information?

Try it out...

Andy